# GTA Online - Bounties

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So currently im being chased because someone has put a bounty on me. But if you commit suicide, lets say you jump off a cliff, do you still have your bounty?

Comment: But do your timer restart if you join another lobby?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you still keep your bounty after suiciding.**

Your bounty will not magically disappear if you decide to take the easy way out.

Comment: I'm removing the disclaimer, as it is still like this on PC. If you want to keep the disclaimer, you can roll back and let me know, and I'll not edit in the future.

Comment: @ardaozkal - it's fine. I don't believe it hurts the post at all and still gets the necessary point across.